# 500 Internal Server Error can't access

Tags: python, odoo

I am using Odoo 8 on Windows 7, things were going all right untill I tried to make the *fleet.vehicle* class inheriting another class (inheritance by prototyping) :

```
_name = 'fleet.vehicle'
_inherit = 'another.class'
```

since then, I have this error when trying to access to my http://localhost:8069/web :

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete
>   your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in
>   the application.

this is the *openerp-server.log*'s repport :

```
2016-03-14 13:59:31,033 1904 INFO Odoo8_DB openerp.modules.loading: loading 1 modules...
2016-03-14 13:59:31,058 1904 INFO Odoo8_DB openerp.modules.loading: 1 modules loaded in 0.02s, 0 queries
2016-03-14 13:59:31,239 1904 INFO Odoo8_DB openerp.modules.loading: loading 53 modules...
2016-03-14 13:59:31,266 1904 CRITICAL Odoo8_DB openerp.modules.module: Couldn't load module fleet
2016-03-14 13:59:31,267 1904 CRITICAL Odoo8_DB openerp.modules.module: unindent does not match any outer indentation level (fleet.py, line 313)
2016-03-14 13:59:31,279 1904 INFO Odoo8_DB werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [14/Mar/2016 13:59:31] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 -
2016-03-14 13:59:31,293 1904 ERROR Odoo8_DB werkzeug: Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "werkzeug\serving.py", line 177, in run_wsgi

  File "werkzeug\serving.py", line 165, in execute

  File "D:\MesDocuments\Les_prog\Odoo 8.0-20160118\server\openerp\service\server.py", line 290, in app
    return self.app(e, s)
  File "D:\MesDocuments\Les_prog\Odoo 8.0-20160118\server\openerp\service\wsgi_server.py", line 216, in application
    return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
  File "D:\MesDocuments\Les_prog\Odoo 8.0-20160118\server\openerp\service\wsgi_server.py", line 202, in application_unproxied
    result = handler(environ, start_response)
  File "D:\MesDocuments\Les_prog\Odoo 8.0-20160118\server\openerp\http.py", line 1290, in __call__
    return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)
  File "D:\MesDocuments\Les_prog\Odoo 8.0-20160118\server\openerp\http.py", line 1428, in dispatch
    ir_http = request.registry['ir.http']
  File "D:\MesDocuments\Les_prog\Odoo 8.0-20160118\server\openerp\http.py", line 346, in registry
    return openerp.modules.registry.RegistryManager.get(self.db) if self.db else None
  File "D:\MesDocuments\Les_prog\Odoo 8.0-20160118\server\openerp\modules\registry.py", line 339, in get
    update_module)
  File "D:\MesDocuments\Les_prog\Odoo 8.0-20160118\server\openerp\modules\registry.py", line 370, in new
    openerp.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "D:\MesDocuments\Les_prog\Odoo 8.0-20160118\server\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 351, in load_modules
    force, status, report, loaded_modules, update_module)
  File "D:\MesDocuments\Les_prog\Odoo 8.0-20160118\server\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 255, in load_marked_modules
    loaded, processed = load_module_graph(cr, graph, progressdict, report=report, skip_modules=loaded_modules, perform_checks=perform_checks)
  File "D:\MesDocuments\Les_prog\Odoo 8.0-20160118\server\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 143, in load_module_graph
    load_openerp_module(package.name)
  File "D:\MesDocuments\Les_prog\Odoo 8.0-20160118\server\openerp\modules\module.py", line 315, in load_openerp_module
    __import__('openerp.addons.' + module_name)
  File "D:\MesDocuments\Les_prog\Odoo 8.0-20160118\server\openerp\modules\module.py", line 80, in load_module
    mod = imp.load_module('openerp.addons.' + module_part, f, path, descr)
  File "D:\MesDocuments\Les_prog\Odoo 8.0-20160118\server\openerp\addons\fleet\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    import fleet
File "D:\MesDocuments\Les_prog\Odoo 8.0-20160118\server\openerp\addons\fleet\fleet.py", line 313
    LogFuel = self.pool['fleet.vehicle.log.fuel']
                                                ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

even after deleting the line I added I am still receiving the same error, 
I tried to restart the odoo-server, postgreSQL-server and refreshing the DB but in vain.. 
  I would be gratful for any help

edit : line 313 , fleet.py 
[image: line 313 in fleet.py]

Comment: Any chance you have edited `fleet.py` from fleet module while examining its code for inheriting it? Also if you want to customize fleet module then you probably need `_inherit = 'fleet.vehicle'` and `_name = 'your_class'`. Not the other way around like you are doing.

Comment: thanks for replying, but I have canceled all editings before asking the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's python-related : you have some trailing (before or after) indent.
Open your file within your IDE, and display indents. In python, each block should be on the same indent level.

EDIT : as the stack says it, that's probably near: `D:\MesDocuments\Les_prog\Odoo 8.0-20160118\server\openerp\addons\fleet\fleet.py", line 313`

Comment: thanks for replying, but I think this is not the real problem (I have added a screenshot of the line 313 )

Comment: Remember : python and trailing spaces / indents. Double check the line before AND after. Error is pretty clear : you have trouble with indents. I'm not a Windows user, but if I remember well, Notepad++ has some option to show invisible characters; use it to find what is causing trouble here.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "trailing indent", and Python does not care about whitespace at the *end* of a line. However, these problems can easily occur when mixing spaces and tabs. Depending on the IDE it may not display in a way that highlights the problem.